# Conditionally constexpr member function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, constexpr

Suppose I have a template class

```
template <typename T>
class foo {
    T m;

    decltype(auto) f() { return m.f(); }
};
```

How can I give `foo:f()` the constexpr specifier only if `T::f()` is constexpr?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just slap a `constexpr` on it:

```
constexpr decltype(auto) f() { return m.f(); }
```

Yes, it's perfectly still valid even if `T::f()` isn't `constexpr`; such a function simply can't be used in constant expressions. See [[dcl.constexpr]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.constexpr#7).