# Conditional constexpr on non-dependent condition

Tags: c++, constexpr, c++20, c++-concepts

Suppose I have a configuration function to be defined by the user of the library which may or may not be `constexpr`.

```
constexpr int iterations() { return 10; }
// Or maybe:
int iterations() { return std::atoi(std::getenv("ITERATIONS")); }

// I'm okay with requiring the constexpr version to be:
constexpr auto iterations() { return std::integral_constant<int, 10>{}; }
```

Now I have a function that has different behavior depending on the value of `iterations()`, but this function should be `constexpr` if `iterations` is, because I want the user to be able to use it in `constexpr` if they configured the library to allow for it:

```
/*constexpr*/ std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x) {
    auto const iterations = ::iterations();

    // For illustration purposes
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        x *= x;
    }

    return x;
}
```

What can I do to `algorithm` to make the function `constexpr` if `iterations()` is? In short, I want something like `constexpr(constexpr(::iterations()))`.

---

Note that "conditional `constexpr`" is usually dependent on a template parameter as in [Conditionally constexpr member function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41517603/1896169) in which case the `constexpr` keyword can just be used, but in this case, I want the `constexpr` to be conditional on something which is *not* a template parameter, but a statically known function. Marking `algorithm` as `constexpr` is a [compilation error](https://godbolt.org/z/9zTaha):

```
error: call to non-'constexpr' function 'bool iterations()'
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290363/5684257.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can silence the compiler diagnostics by ensuring that there is *some* set of template parameters and function arguments for which a call to your function is a constant expression even if `::iterations()` is *not* a constant expression. For example:

```cpp
template <bool True = true>
constexpr std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x) {
    if constexpr (True) {
        auto const iterations = ::iterations();

        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
            x *= x;
        }

        return x;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

`algorithm<false>(meow)` is a constant expression whenever `meow` is, so a compiler cannot complain (https://godbolt.org/z/GvE9ME).

Comment: This sort of makes a mockery out of the rule though, no? Kind of like, no you can't do `static_assert(false);` but yes you can do `static_assert(always_false_v<T>);`

Comment: @Barry Yes it does. It would be nice if there were a more explicit way to opt out of some of the "helpful" checks the language provides for templates, but absent that, we have gnarly workounds. `template <bool B> struct S { template <bool BB = B, class = enable_if_t<BB>> // ...` is the classic case - which we fixed in the core language with requires-clauses - but certainly not the only case.

Answer (score 2):

Taking inspiration from your answer, you can use concepts to impose that `iteration()` return a integral constant.

The important part is remember that `algorithm()` ha to be a template function or concept (`requires`) can't works, so you can impose an unused and defaulted template parameter

```
//VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV <-- add this to activate `requires`  
  template <typename = void>
  constexpr std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x)
          requires is_integral_constant<decltype(::iterations())>
   { return ::algorithm_impl(x, ::iterations()); }
```

The following is your example simplified

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_integral_constant = false;

template <typename T, T value>
constexpr bool is_integral_constant<std::integral_constant<T, value>> = true;

constexpr std::uint32_t algorithm_impl(std::uint32_t x, int iterations) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        x *= x;
    }

    return x;
}

template <typename = void>
constexpr std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x)
        requires is_integral_constant<decltype(::iterations())>
 { return ::algorithm_impl(x, ::iterations()); }

std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x) {
    return ::algorithm_impl(x, ::iterations());
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you can use `requires` on non-templates (you certainly can for a non-template inside a templated class) and that GCC's complaint is just that their concepts implementation is incomplete. Regardless, this is an excellent way to get around the issues of the compiler instantiating the body of `algorithm` against the constraint.

Comment: @Justin - According [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints), "Class templates, function templates, and non-template functions (typically members of class templates) may be associated with a constraint, which specifies the requirements on template arguments", so (if I understand correctly) "template arguments" are required.

Comment: @Justin - The surreal aspect is that this solution works also if the template parameter isn't involved.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm okay with requiring the constexpr version to be: ... `std::integral_constant<int, 10>`

Because you are okay with requiring the `constexpr` version of the function to have a different return type, we can detect this special type and condition the `constexpr` on that by using constraints (C++20's `requires`). Note that we have to further wrap the body in `if constexpr` because the compiler still checks the body of the function:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_integral_constant = false;

template <typename T, T value>
constexpr bool is_integral_constant<std::integral_constant<T, value>> = true;

constexpr std::uint32_t algorithm_impl(std::uint32_t x, int iterations) {
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        x *= x;
    }

    return x;
}

constexpr std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x)
        requires is_integral_constant<decltype(::iterations())> {
    if constexpr (is_integral_constant<decltype(::iterations())>) {
        return ::algorithm_impl(x, ::iterations());
    } else {
        // Unreachable, but enough to convince the compiler that there is a
        // constexpr friendly path through the function
        return 0xDEADBEEF;
    }
}

std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x) {
    return ::algorithm_impl(x, ::iterations());
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/svKGKM)

Comment: Question: if you impose `requires is_integral_constant<decltype(::iterations())>`, why you check `if constexpr (is_integral_constant<decltype(::iterations())>)` inside the body? Isn't ever true?

Comment: I mean: what's wrong with simply `constexpr std::uint32_t algorithm(std::uint32_t x) requires is_integral_constant<decltype(::iterations())> { return ::algorithm_impl(x, ::iterations()); }` ?

Comment: @max66 Yes, it is always true, but without the check and just having `return :;algorithm_impl(x, ::iterations())`, the compiler complains that the `constexpr` function is never constexpr (the only path calls the non-constexpr `::iterations()`)

Comment: This is the part I don't understand: "the only path calls the non-constexpr `::iterations()`". Given (`require`) that `decltype(::iterations())` is an integral constant, how can be "non-constexpr"?

Comment: @max66 See https://godbolt.org/z/ooY8bW . I don't know what in the standard makes this happen, but it does (it could even be a bug in clang's concepts implementation)

Comment: Added an answer to explain where the problem is.